# S3 Sends Message to SQS and EC2 Script Checks If Message Exists

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sqs

I have a S3 bucket which sends a message to my SQS queue when a new item has been added to the bucket. My plan was to then have a script on my EC2 server which is ran every 10 minutes using cron, this script would check if a message exists in the SQS queue.

I have given the S3 bucket permission to send messages into my SQS queue but now I am struggling how to allow my EC2 to read messages from the SQS queue due to permissions.

Below is my Policy, my question is how do I also allow a IAM role and my S3 bucket permission to READ/SEND messages.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "arn:aws:sqs:eu-west-1:446971925991:S3-Probe-Data-Imported/SQSDefaultPolicy",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "example-statement-ID",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "SQS:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:eu-west-1:446971925991:S3-Probe-Data-Imported",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnLike": {
          "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:s3:*:*:probe-request-backups"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I have attached the `AmazonSQSReadOnlyAccess` policy to the IAM role that my EC2 server will use to read messages from the SQS queue.

I'm presuming this is possible but if not how could I trigger an EC2 script (not lambda) once a new item has been added to my S3 bucket.

Answer (score 1):

The IAM Role associated with the EC2 instance needs to include **more than just read-only permissions** because, once a message has been processed, the program will need to call SQS again to delete the message. (While a message is being processed, it is placed in an 'Invisible' state. If the program does not delete the message within a specific time period, SQS will assume that the program failed and the message will reappear on the queue.) Therefore, it also needs `sqs:DeleteMessage` permissions.

To permit the S3 bucket to send a message to the SQS queue, the queue's **Policy Document** must be edited to include appropriate permissions.

See: [Walkthrough: Configure a bucket for notifications (SNS topic or SQS queue) - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ways-to-add-notification-config-to-bucket.html)

An alternative to using EC2 to process the messages is to **trigger an AWS Lambda function** that can process the message. This can work out much lower-cost and it can process messages immediately after they are placed in the S3 bucket.